# Как сделать полу рандомную анимацию?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать так, чтоб сначала проигрывалась анимация по одному, а иногда немного по другому.

**Пример**: Есть 2 лампочки, 1-вая мигает постоянно, 2-ая мигает по случайному, может мигнуть, может нет. Главное, чтобы это не была просто "гиф" где она просто иногда мигает через одинаковый промежуток времени.

Comment: Может сделать это скриптом?

Comment: От чего должна зависеть полу-случайность мигания второй лампочки?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer не от чего, просто время между ее мигами всегда должно быть разным

Comment: Очень плохой пример, "свечение лампочки" - это не анимация. Вернее это можно сделать и через анимацию, но это бредовая затея. Нужно смотреть в сторону State Machine.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker можно сделать одну анимацию и менять ее скорость случаным образом, получится очень лаконично

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну вот опять же, нужен конкретный пример анимации. Если это действительно лампочка, то анимация для нее не нужна. Если это набор анимаций, которые могут перетекать друг в друга, то можно применить все тот же автомат, только нужно грамотно реализовать все переходы через тот же `Random.Range`. Ну и да, скорость самой анимации можно менять, если это не повредит визуализации - это придаст еще большей "случайности".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Анимация - это, обычно, конечный автомат или машина состояний *(англ. state machine)*, в Unity для контроллера анимации она как раз и используется. В вопросе был приведен пример со свечением лампочки, однако свечение лампочки - не есть анимация в общем случае, она либо горит, либо не горит.

Воспользовавшись обычным `Random.Range` и корутиной с `WaitForSeconds`:

```
public class StateMachine : MonoBehaviour {
    enum State {
        Off,
        On
    }

    State state = State.Off;

    [SerializeField]
    Vector2 stateChangeTimerBorders;

    Material material;

    private void Start() {
        material = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
        StartCoroutine(StateRoutine());
    }

    IEnumerator StateRoutine() {
        while (true) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(UnityEngine.Random.Range(stateChangeTimerBorders.x, stateChangeTimerBorders.y));

            // Меняем состояние
            state++;
            if(state > State.On) {
                state = State.Off;
            }

            // Меняем свойства объекта в зависимости от стейта
            switch (state) {
                case State.Off:
                    material.SetColor("_Color", Color.white);
                    break;
                case State.On:
                    material.SetColor("_Color", Color.yellow);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Unknown state {0}", state));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Можно получить такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]